# SQL server and client for Ubuntu (Debian)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sql-server, sql

I have been using MS IIS server and MS Sql client Management Studio at workplace on Windows system. My home system is a Ubuntu system and I like setup a database server and a client to interact with the database. So I want recommendations on the server software and client I can go for in Ubuntu

Platform: Ubuntu/Linux
License: Free

SQL client: With GUI, allowing queries, (auto complete/intellisence is advantageous)

SQL server: should support relational database.

I am expecting multiple answers and chose the one I like after trying them all.

Comment: [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)?

Comment: Do you want to have "open-source" or "gratis" when you say "free"?

Comment: I agree with @ChrisBurton - MySql is the way to go. It is one of the most widely used and supported databases around. MySqlWorkBench is a great tool, for designing databases, reverse engineering them and for CRUD.  If you need to learn something new, I would suggest that you stick to ODBC in case you ever switch database systems again. You might miss out on a few features that are specific to a particular database type, but you won't have to rewrite any software to switch database systems - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity

Comment: Pretty broad I'd say. An "SQL server supporting a relational database" is like "a car with wheels", or "past history" :) Same for an "SQL client allowing queries". There are much more details needed here: how much data is to be stored (for up to several MiB, SQLite is fine and x-platform – for several TiB even MySQL might have trouble), what needs to interface with it (web server? SAP clients?) Please read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185), and then see if you can [edit] and improve your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/).

It is a very advanced relational database system. Its very close to the ANSI-SQL:2008 standard and has a lot of features that might come in handy further down the road.

If you are just starting to get to know relational databases Postgres will teach you a lot of function that you will find (in one way or another) in other [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) as well.

Postgres comes with its own client called pgAdmin3. It also has a command line interface if you require one.

MS-SQL and Postgres are similar to each other that most stuff "just works" but they are sufficiently different to each other that a lot of stuff requires learning.

Postgres has lots and lots and lots of documentation and tutorials so you will find it easy to find the answers to your questions.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-setup-database-server-with-postgresql-and-pgadmin3.html) to setup the database and first user etc.